# Materialize - Como alinhar o rodapé sempre abaixo?

Tags: css, materialize

Este código abaixo deixa ele alinhado abaixo caso o conteúdo preencha toda a página, caso contrário ele fica no meio do corpo.

Observação: Já li o manual do materialize, até ficou alinhado mas descaracterizou o menu lateral.

Também já tentei `style='vertical-align=bottom;'` sem sucesso.

```html
<!-- INÍCIO DO RODAPÉ -->
  <footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- FIM DO RODAPÉ -->
```

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer, é criar uma classe no seu CSS colocando o seguinte código:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

amigo tenta assim no seu arquivo CSS

```css
   

 /*No seu body*/

   html, body {
     height: 100%;
     }
      
    /*Na primeira div do seu html */

    #NomeDaSuaPrimeiraDiv {
     min-height: 100%;
     }
      
    * html #NomeDaSuaPrimeiraDiv {
     height: 100%; 
     }
      
      /*Posicionando o rodapé*/
    #NomeDaSuaPrimeiraDiv {
     position: relative;
     }

    #page-footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     }
```

espero que isso te ajude se não funciona acessa esse link http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/rodape-embaixo-da-janela.php aqui esta explicando como posicionar o seu rodapé pode ter ficado um pouco confuso a minha explicação então acesse esse o link que coloquei nesse site explica melhor